# how to find the difference in time such as 9.00 AM and 1.00 PM

Tags: php, timestamp

i have two times for example start up time as 9.00 AM and end time as 1.00 PM and i m getting this two times from a dropdown list.How to find the difference between this two times in hours only..

Comment: Have you looked at converting the values to timestamp, then subtracting and finding the difference?

Comment: if it's a dropdown list, make the "value" a number from 0 to 23 and calculate with that. The displayed label can still be "9.00 AM".

Comment: Check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and all related links in there

Comment: ok once i made the value into 0 to 23. How do i subract them using php

Comment: @HakimNaib Simple mathematical symbols, `-` to subtract. `+` to add, `*` to multiply and `/` to divide.. So you will look for `$Difference = $Var_1 - $Var_2;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$to_time = strtotime("09:00:00");
$from_time = strtotime("13:00:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60 / 60 ,2). " Hours";
```

In case you are not sure you can convert your time in 24hr format using

```
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:00 PM"));
```

Comment: What do you mean one type of input? you will have to pass the dynamic value to strtotime.. Do you expect someone to guess even the variable name of your code?